# TinyMCE can't align header tags

Tags: tinymce, umbraco

Does anyone know how I can enable text alignment of header tags through the TinyMCE interface? If I select the text (of any header tag) and select an aligment option it appears to have lined up correctly in the editor. However, when I save the page it gets shifted back to the default alignment (in my case left).

I have also tried editing the HTML directly but when I close the dialog the HTML doesn't seem to update.

I found some documentation on the wiki about the [extended_valid_elements](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/extended_valid_elements) which I tried to update in the `tiny_mce.js` file but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Here is the `valid_elements' setting for the header tags from the tinyMceConfig.config file:

`-h1[id|dir|class|align],-h2[id|dir|class|align],
-h3[id|dir|class|align],-h4[id|dir|class|align],-h5[id|dir|class|align],-h6[id|style|dir|class|align]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just for anyone who has a similar issue, I managed to resolve this.

The editor attempts to apply the `style` attribute to header tags when you select any of the alignment options, by default this is not enabled in the `valid_elements` configuration.

In order to get this to work you just need to add the `style` attribute to the configuration for each header e.g. `-h1[id|dir|class|align|style], -h2[id|dir|class|align|style]` etc

If using Umbraco you need to make these changes in the `~/config/tinyMceConfig.config` file and then recycle the app pool your site is running under.

Answer (score 1):

What about [valid_elements](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/valid_elements)? I think this should be the right setting for you, because header tags are valid xhtml tags, you do not need extended_valid_elements.

Comment: Hi, I checked the valid elements and it appears to be configured correctly, see my question I have posted the configuration from the tinyMceConfig file.

Comment: is this behaviour to be seen on one of the examples pages from moviecode(http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/full.php)?

Comment: hmm, could you please post your full configuration?

Comment: I managed to figure out what the problem was. I installed a local version of umbraco 4 and ran it straight out of the box. Same issue, I looked at the configuration in the tinyMceConfig.config file and noticed that the `align` attribute was enabled for the header tags....but when you select the align options in the editor it trys to set the `style` attribute not the align! So I updated the config file to allow the style attribute for the tags and hey presto it worked. Tried the same changes on my live site but it never seems to update, any idea's?

Comment: I have already restarted umbraco 3-4 times and even deleted history etc to make sure it wasn't a cache problem.

Comment: glad you found the solution yourself

Comment: Yeah, been an absolute pain in the @ss! I managed to fix the issue on the live server aswell, I had to recycle the app pool.

Comment: +1 for your help as eventually I narrowed the problem down to being related to the valid_elements, just had to use the process of elimination!